# How to publish node in a specific region

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I created several regions and I added several blocks within these regions.
I created a Node and it's being displayed within the "content" block.
I need to know how to display a Node in a different block ("Sidebar", "Top bar" etc.).

I watched several screencasts about Views, Content-Type etc.
I couldn't find a way to solve this problem.
I know it seems ridiculous, but I've been working on other frameworks (Yii, Joomla, Wordpress ...) and it was very straightforward.

Any help is appreciated.

Best Regards, Wissam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually have to use a block to place content in a specific region. Content, Sidebar, and Top Bar are considered regions. Blocks can be managed from the admin/structure/block screen. You can either create a block right from that screen, or create a block view in Views and it will appear in that list. Then you can move it to whichever region you'd like.